What is the name of old lego racing animated series?
I remember watching a lego animated "cartoon" somewhere back in nineties but I can't seem to be able to google the name of it. I remember episodes about cars/formulas racing each other. It could be that there were also some different episodes than racing but I don't remember if there was. Does anyone remember what it was called?

@KutF hehe, no it's not mask. but thanks for the try =)

Searching through Google supplied this:. I don't know if it is part of a series, though the site contains other videos which seem aimed at selling Legos and sets specific to the plots. This specific "mini-movie" is about five minutes long at most.UPDATE: Actually, from the site search, I can't even tell if there are any more LEGO films there, or when this one was created.UPDATE2: The Lego Site provides a series of animations that ARE linked to specific racer sets here.
